# Should I not use inheritance when I need subtype cast/instantiation from basetype?

Tags: java, object-oriented

## Problem

`BaseType` has a field `String jsonData` that represents a JSON string.
The structure of the JSON string differs according to a field `String dataType`.
`SubTypeA`, `SubTypeB`, `SubTypeC` all `extends BaseType`, each having additional methods that parses `super.getJsonData()` appropriately.
A pseudo code of the intended usage is as follows:

```java
for (el : baseTypeList) {
    if (el.getDataType.equals("A")) {
        result.add(((SubTypeA)el).getAlphaValueFromJson()); // ClassCastException
    }
    if (el.getDataType.equals("B")) {
        result.add(((SubTypeB)el).getBetaValueFromJson()); // ClassCastException
    }
}
```

However, this code wouldn't work since it's trying to cast Parent into Child.
Another way I could think of for getting around this problem is making an `instanceBy()` method for each of the `SubTypeA`, `SubTypeB` like below:

```java
public class SubTypeA extends BaseType {
    private BaseType baseType;
    public static SubTypeA instanceBy(BaseType baseType) {
        SubTypeA subTypeA = new SubTypeA();
        subTypeA.setBaseType(baseType);
        return subTypeA;
    }
}
```

but as you can see, there's no reason to use inheritence in this case at all, since we won't be accessing `super`. Instead, we'd be using it directly from the field like: `this.baseType.baseTypeSharedMethod();`, `this.baseType.getJsonData();`.
I'm not sure what kind of a design pattern I should be using for this peculiar use-case.

Comment: This code: `result.add((SubTypeA)el.getAlphaValueFromJson())` doesn't look right.  It should be `result.add(((SubTypeA)el).getAlphaValueFromJson())`.  See the extra parentheses around the cast?

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks, I've edited accordingly.

Comment: Oh, so it still doesn't work?

Comment: As I said, it's intended to show a wrong code - it's using inheritance backwards - at least in Java, it's impossible to cast a Parent(Basetype) into a Child(Subtype). Only the other way is possible(Bunch of different subtypes cast into basetype)

Comment: So you're trying to call a super method from a subtype?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is creating a specialized parse method for various children. Children will parse the Parent's field `jsonData`. The main issue is that from the db repository, `List<Parent>`will be returned. According to the Parent's `dataType`, it should be cast into a different child. However, polymorphism is about generalizing children into a single parent, and not the other way around of parent -> child casting. I don't think inheritance is appropriate for this case, and I'm trying to figure out what design I need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but as you can see, there's no reason to use inheritence in this case at all, since we won't be accessing `super`

You are right that there is no point in making `SubTypeX` inherit from `BaseType`, but this does not mean that you are on the wrong track altogether. Amongst others the [GOF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) promoted using composition over inheritance (Favor Composition over Inheritance [*FCoI*], see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance), [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/06/why-favor-composition-over-inheritance-java-oops-design.html)), which means, that its often justified to compose an object from other objects, rather than inherit the respective class from a base class.

The reasons for *FCoI* are that base classes and inherited classes are very tightly coupled, which will eventually lead to code that is less evolvable. Furthermore it's easier to understand what a class does when *FCoI* is applied.

Getting back to your issue: I'd drop the `extends BaseType` from `SubTypeX` altogether (for convenience I will keep the name anyway, even though it ain't a base type anymore) and introduce an interface

```
public interface JsonParser
{
    public string getJsonValue();
}
```

your former subtype will now implement this interface and take the *"base"* via its constructor (you could still use the `static` method to create the instance, which is convenient to name the way you create your instance, but if there is is no way for a `SubTypeA` to exist without an instance of `BaseType`, you could legitemately skip this). `SubTypeA` will look like this

```
public class SubTypeA implements JsonParser
{
    private BaseType instanceOfBaseType;

    public SubTypeA(BaseType baseType)
    {
        instanceOfBaseType = baseType;
    }

    public string getJsonValue()
    {
        // do whatever you have to do
    }
}
```

Your top level code does not need to know whether `SubTypeA` has to do something with `BaseType`. You can push this knowledge down the hierarchy (of instances, not of inheritance). It's even conceivable that an object that inherits from `JsonParser` does not use `BaseType` **at all**.

Furthermore, if you have to make a decision what instance to create, I'd argue to leave this decision to a factory.